# AutoMapper and Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor, automapper

I am using **AutoMapper** with **ITypeConverter** and I want to keep everything within *Castle Windsor*.
In one assembly I have my **ITypeCoverter** and I load them using this approach:

```
container
.Register(Types.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
.BasedOn(typeof(ITypeConverter<,>)));
```

So far so good I can see that Windsor is loading all my converters properly.

Then I register AutoMapper within Windsor

```
Mapper.Initialize(m => m.ConstructServicesUsing(container.Resolve));
container.Register(Component.For<IMappingEngine>().Instance(Mapper.Engine));
```

But when I ask an instance of IMappingEngine the conventions are not loaded. Do I miss something here?

Answer (score 3):

I got AutoMapper and Windsor to play nicely together with both Profiles and TypeConverters. I think this should be agnostic enough for you, since AutoMapper will automatically pick up any implementations of ITypeConverter.

Let me know if it solves your problem.

First I registered AutoMapper with Windsor:

```cs
public class AutoMapperInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        // Replace by whatever assembly contains your ITypeConverter, IValueResolver and Profile implementations
        var myAssembly = Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("MyAssembly");

        // Register AutoMapper such that it uses a singleton configuration
        container.Register(
            myAssembly.BasedOn(typeof(ITypeConverter<,>)).WithServiceSelf(),
            myAssembly.BasedOn<IValueResolver>().WithServiceBase(),
            myAssembly.BasedOn<Profile>().WithServiceBase(),
            Component.For<IEnumerable<IObjectMapper>>().UsingFactoryMethod(() => MapperRegistry.Mappers),
            Component.For<ConfigurationStore>()
                .LifestyleSingleton()
                .UsingFactoryMethod(x =>
                {
                    var typeMapFactory = x.Resolve<ITypeMapFactory>();
                    var mappers = x.Resolve<IEnumerable<IObjectMapper>>();
                    ConfigurationStore configurationStore = new ConfigurationStore(typeMapFactory, mappers);
                    configurationStore.ConstructServicesUsing(x.Resolve);
                    configurationStore.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
                    return configurationStore;
                }),
            Component.For<IConfigurationProvider>().UsingFactoryMethod(x => x.Resolve<ConfigurationStore>()),
            Component.For<IConfiguration>().UsingFactoryMethod(x => x.Resolve<ConfigurationStore>()),
            Component.For<IMappingEngine>().ImplementedBy<MappingEngine>().LifestyleSingleton(),
            Component.For<ITypeMapFactory>().ImplementedBy<TypeMapFactory>()
        );

        // Add all Profiles
        var configuration = container.Resolve<IConfiguration>();
        container.ResolveAll<Profile>().ToList().ForEach(configuration.AddProfile);
    }
}
```

Then I created a Profile where I registered all the ITypeConverter implementations using a bit of reflection:

```cs
public class TypeConverterProfile : Profile
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public TypeConverterProfile(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        // Replace by whatever assembly contains your ITypeConverter implementations
        var myAssembly = Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("MyAssembly");
        var typeConverters =
            from x in myAssembly.GetTypes()
            from type in x.GetInterfaces()
            where type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ITypeConverter<,>)
            select new
            {
                Type = x,
                Source = type.GetGenericArguments()[0],
                Destination = type.GetGenericArguments()[1]
            };

        // Apply type converters to AutoMapper configuration
        foreach (var typeConverter in typeConverters)
            _configuration.CreateMap(typeConverter.Source, typeConverter.Destination).ConvertUsing(typeConverter.Type);
    }
}
```

AutoMapper will now automatically pick up and use any Profiles and ITypeConverters implementations in "MyAssembly".

As an example, you may have a Profile:

```cs
public class MapProfile : Profile
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public MapProfile(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        // Create an auto-map from SearchResultModel -> SearchResult
        _configuration.CreateMap<SearchResultModel, SearchResult>();
    }
}
```

And an ITypeConverter:

```cs
public class SearchRequestConverter : ITypeConverter<SearchRequest, SearchRequestModel>
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public MapProfile(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        // Also in the ITypeConverter you may have the IConfiguration injected in case you need it
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public SearchRequestModel Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var model = (SearchRequest) context.SourceValue;
        return new SearchRequestModel
        {
            Results = model.Results
        };
    }
}
```

Finally you perform the actual mapping in your class by having a dependency on the IMappingEngine:

```cs
public class FolderRepository
{
    private readonly IMappingEngine _mappingEngine;

    public FolderRepository(IMappingEngine mappingEngine)
    {
        _mappingEngine = mappingEngine;
    }

    public SearchResult Search(SearchRequest searchRequest)
    {
        // This mapping will use the ITypeConverter implementation
        SearchRequestModel searchRequestModel = _mappingEngine.Map<SearchRequestModel>(searchRequest);
        SearchResultModel searchResultModel = Search(searchRequestModel);

        // This mapping will use the auto-map from the Profile
        SearchResult searchResult = _mappingEngine.Map<SearchResultModel>(searchResultModel);
        return searchResult;
    }

    private SearchResultModel Search(SearchRequestModel searchRequestModel)
    {
        SearchResultModel result = new SearchResultModel();
        // ... perform search ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

To have more ITypeConverters, you just have to implement them, and they will automagically be picked up by Windsor and AutoMapper. Manual auto-maps (CreateMap<>) can be added in a Profile.

Does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

**I see no code that creates/ setups mappings. Neither `Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();` nor `configuration.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();`**

Unfortunately, there isn't enough information about using IoC and AutoMapper together. You can find only one [an example of usage AutoMapper and Structure Map in the official samples](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/develop/src/AutoMapperSamples/InversionOfControl.cs).

There is also [my example of usage AutoMapper and Castle Windsor](https://github.com/ilyapalkin/ToolTesting/blob/master/ToolTesting.AutoMapper/InversionOfControl/CastleWindsorIntegration.cs). It is the similar to previous one, but Castle Windsor is used instead of Structure Map.

```
/// <summary>
/// Castle Windsor example.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// StructureMap example
/// see  https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/develop/src/AutoMapperSamples/CastleWindsorIntegration.cs
/// </remarks>
public class CastleWindsorIntegration
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer container;

    public CastleWindsorIntegration()
    {
        container = new WindsorContainer();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Example()
    {
        container.Install(new ConfigurationInstaller());

        var configuration1 = container.Resolve<IConfiguration>();
        var configuration2 = container.Resolve<IConfiguration>();
        configuration1.Should().BeSameAs(configuration2);

        var configurationProvider = container.Resolve<IConfigurationProvider>();
        configurationProvider.Should().BeSameAs(configuration1);

        var configuration = container.Resolve<ConfigurationStore>();
        configuration.Should().BeSameAs(configuration1);

        configuration1.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();

        var engine = container.Resolve<IMappingEngine>();

        var destination = engine.Map<Source, Destination>(new Source { Value = 15 });

        destination.Value.Should().Be(15);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Example2()
    {
        container.Install(new MappingEngineInstaller());

        Mapper.Reset();

        Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();

        var engine = container.Resolve<IMappingEngine>();

        var destination = engine.Map<Source, Destination>(new Source { Value = 15 });

        destination.Value.Should().Be(15);
    }

    public class Source
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Destination
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConfigurationInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(
                Component.For<IEnumerable<IObjectMapper>>()
                    .LifestyleSingleton()
                    .UsingFactoryMethod(() => MapperRegistry.Mappers),
                Component.For<ConfigurationStore>().ImplementedBy<ConfigurationStore>(),
                Component.For<IConfigurationProvider>().UsingFactoryMethod(k => k.Resolve<ConfigurationStore>()),
                Component.For<IConfiguration>().UsingFactoryMethod(k => k.Resolve<ConfigurationStore>()),
                Component.For<IMappingEngine>().ImplementedBy<MappingEngine>(),
                Component.For<ITypeMapFactory>().ImplementedBy<TypeMapFactory>());
        }
    }

    public class MappingEngineInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(
                Component.For<IMappingEngine>().UsingFactoryMethod(() => Mapper.Engine));
        }
    }
}
```

In order to make the test green it is needed to use `Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ConvertUsing<SourceToDestinqtionConvertor>();` for example.

```
    [Fact]
    public void Example3()
    {
        container
            .Register(Types.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
            .BasedOn(typeof(ITypeConverter<,>)));

        Mapper.Initialize(m => m.ConstructServicesUsing(container.Resolve));
        container.Register(Component.For<IMappingEngine>().Instance(Mapper.Engine));

        var engine = container.Resolve<IMappingEngine>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ConvertUsing<SourceToDestinqtionConvertor>();

        var destination = engine.Map<Source, Destination>(new Source { Value = 15 });

        destination.Value.Should().Be(15);
    }

    public class SourceToDestinqtionConvertor : ITypeConverter<Source, Destination>
    {
        public Destination Convert(ResolutionContext context)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

In order be able to resolve 'ITypeConverter' it is needed to specify which service are going to be used.

```
        container
            .Register(Types.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
            .BasedOn(typeof(ITypeConverter<,>))
            .WithService.AllInterfaces());

        // Makes sure that type converter can be resolved
        var resolver = container.Resolve<ITypeConverter<Source, Destination>>();
        resolver.Should().BeOfType<SourceToDestinqtionConvertor>();
```

Comment: Yes this is what's needed but become quite useless cause in each profile you must be "aware" of the converter, while I was looking for a complete agnostic solution where AutoMapper figures it out.
Anyway I just spoke with AutoMapper team and there is a plan to add this functionality in the framework to fully dynamically load mapping configuration without using the suntac Mapper.CreateMap ...

Comment: Yes, it would be useful since it is needed to develop additional abstractions to invoke `Mapper.CreateMap()` via IoC now.

Answer (score 0):

I do the following to make Automapper works.

1st at registration point:

```
        foreach (var automapperProfileType in types.Where(t => t.IsInterface == false && typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(t)))
        {
            container.Register(
                Component.For(typeof(Profile))
                    .ImplementedBy(automapperProfileType)
                    .LifestyleTransient()
                    .Named("AutoMapper / Profile / " + automapperProfileType.FullName));
            automapperProfileTypes.Add(automapperProfileType);
        }
```

And then then after initialization of all types:

```
        foreach (var profileMap in container.ResolveAll<Profile>())
        {
            Mapper.AddProfile(profileMap);
        }
```

Hope that helps.